# lerna run `lerna version patch` throw error git remote update Permission denied?

Tags: git

I use lerna and want to use `lerna version` to manage my version。
I add password to my ssh key.
I can do `git remote update` by inputted my password .
But i cannot use `lerna version patch` and it give me the error:

```
> lerna-demo@1.0.0 patch
> lerna version patch --conventional-commits --yes

lerna notice cli v4.0.0
lerna info current version 1.0.0
lerna ERR! Error: Command failed with exit code 1: git remote update
lerna ERR! git@gitee.com: Permission denied (publickey).
lerna ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
lerna ERR!
lerna ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
lerna ERR! and the repository exists.
lerna ERR! error: could not fetch origin
lerna ERR! Fetching origin
lerna ERR!     at makeError (D:\code\lerna-demo\node_modules\execa\lib\error.js:60:11)
lerna ERR!     at Function.module.exports.sync (D:\code\lerna-demo\node_modules\execa\index.js:194:17)
lerna ERR!     at Object.execSync (D:\code\lerna-demo\node_modules\@lerna\child-process\index.js:39:16)
lerna ERR!     at updateRemote (D:\code\lerna-demo\node_modules\@lerna\version\lib\is-behind-upstream.js:34:16)
lerna ERR!     at isBehindUpstream (D:\code\lerna-demo\node_modules\@lerna\version\lib\is-behind-upstream.js:16:3)
lerna ERR!     at VersionCommand.initialize (D:\code\lerna-demo\node_modules\@lerna\version\index.js:153:9)
lerna ERR! lerna Command failed with exit code 1: git remote update
lerna ERR! lerna git@gitee.com: Permission denied (publickey).
lerna ERR! lerna fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
lerna ERR! lerna
lerna ERR! lerna Please make sure you have the correct access rights
lerna ERR! lerna and the repository exists.
lerna ERR! lerna error: could not fetch origin
lerna ERR! lerna Fetching origin
```

Comment: Looks like the repository is requireing the use of public key authentication.

Comment: @Ramhound A public key with password will cause this error. And I remove the password of the key lerna just works. But I need the password.

Comment: The error specifically says the permissions on the public key, on the server, isn't correct.